# Working with TableViews and CollectionViews and managing multiple data sources in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a main ViewController, `MainViewController` that contains a number of views along with a `TableView`.

Each row (i.e. `tableViewCell`) contains different content from different sources/views etc.  A number of those rows in the tableView, in turn, contain a `CollectionView` called `SettingsCollectionView`.  In the `tableView`'s `cellForRowAt` method, I initialize the `SettingsCollectionView` for that `tableViewCell` and also pass it the respective data which that `CollectionView` subclass uses as its data source. So for example:

`tableView` row 0 - contains generic content

`tableView` row 1 - `settingsCollectionViewA : SettingsCollectionView` as well as a struct `OriginalDataA`

`tableView` row 2 - contains generic content

`tableView` row 3 - `settingsCollectionViewB : SettingsCollectionView` as well as a struct `OriginalDataB`

`tableView` row 4 - `settingsCollectionViewC : SettingsCollectionView`as well as a struct `OriginalDataC`

`tableView` row 5 - contains generic content

When I initialize `settingsCollectionViewA` with `OriginalDataA`, I have a setter in that `CollectionView` that then sets up the local data under `LocalDataA`.  This allows me to ensure I have the original and the working copy of the data based on the user making changes etc.  Any time I call the `OriginalDataA` variable from the `MainViewController`, a getter in `settingsCollectionViewA` does some cleaning up of the data etc. so I can then do what I want with it in the `MainViewController`.

That part all works well except if those tableView cells are dequeued, when they reappear, I get back the original state for that `tableViewCell` and in turn collectionView rather than the state the user left it in.

I realize this is because each `SettingsCollectionView` class is working its own local copy of `OriginalDataA`, `OriginalDataB` etc. and appreciate I can just update the *original data* but then that creates other complexities - like the cleanness of current 'standalone' code built for the `SettingsCollectionView` subclass as well as the complexity of original vs. updated data.  That's why I am stuck on a better programming approach...

Apologies, this might seem like a basic question but I'm new to programming and all the examples etc. I can find all speak to more simple scenarios rather than what I'm trying to do.

I haven't included the code because it's got a whole lot of other content and functionality that I think just confuses the concept outlined above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your originalDataA etc structs or classes?

Comment: They are structs

Comment: If they are structs you will need your view controller to hold the working copy as well as the original and update the working copy via delegation or callback closures.  If you make the data classes then you can have the view controller hold a reference to the working copy instance and keep the updates in the cells. Another, perhaps better, alternative is to create a class to hold your working copy structs and pass this class instance to the cells

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  I think I'm just confused though on how to update say, `copyOfOriginalDataA`.  If I inject it into the `SettingsCollectionView`, then it's not a variable available throughout the `SettingsCollecdtionView` but only in that method.  So trying to use it in e.g. `numberOfItemsInSection` etc. is getting me stumped.  I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here!!

Comment: @Paulw11is correct, you need to have the orignalData, copy of orignalData on which you will work. And a update the orignalCopy when your work is done with copyOfOrignalData. 

I think you should also move to class instead of structure if you are adding/updating/resetting the data

Comment: That is why you need to create a class that holds all of your struct instances.  Pass this class instance to your cells, not the struct.  Then when you update the struct in the class the view controller has the same class instance with the new/updated  struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class that holds each of your data structs:

```
class MyDataModel {
    var dataA: DataA
    var dataB: DataB
    var dataC: DataC
}
```

Then you create an instance of `MyDataModel` and hold a reference to it in a property of your view controller.  Pass this same instance to your table view cells.  Since it is a class and therefore a reference type, changes made by the cell will actually be made in this one instance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider you have **SettingsCollectionViewA** which shows **originalDataA**. CollectionView displays the data what you provide in cellforrowatindex method. Collection view cells reuse memory every time. Only visible cells stays in the memory at any point of time. So user modified data will not be stored explicitly unless you modify the originalDataA.

Comment: This answer basically restates the original problem.  It doesn't really propose a solution